# C bit field variables are printing unexpected values

Tags: c, bit

```
struct m

{
   int parent:3;

   int child:3;

   int mother:2;
};

void main()
{

   struct m son={2,-6,5};

   printf("%d %d %d",son.parent,son.child,son.mother);
}
```

Can anybody please help in telling why the output of the program is `2 2 1` ?

Answer (score 27):

Taking out all but the significant bits for the fields shown:

```
parent: 3 bits (1-sign bit + 2 more), value 010, result 2
child:  3 bits (1-sign bit + 2 more), value 010, result 2
mother: 2 bits (1 sign bit + 1 more), value  01, result 1
```

---

**Details**

It bears pointing out that your structure fields are declared as `int` bit-field values. By C99-§6.7.2,2, the following types are all equivalent: `int`, `signed`, or `signed int`. Therefore, your structure fields are *signed*. By C99-§6.2.6.2,2, one of your bits shall be consumed in representing the "sign" of the variable (negative or positive). Further, the same section states that excluding the sign-bit, the remaining bits representation must correspond to an associated *unsigned* type of the remaining bit-count. C99-§6.7.2,1 clearly defines how each of these bits represents a power of 2. Therefore, the only bit that is normally used as the sign-bit is the most significant bit (its the only one that is left, but I'm quite sure if this is an inaccurate interpretation of the standard I'll hear about it in due time). That you are assigning a negative number as one of your test values used for your sample suggests you *may* be aware of this, but many people newly exposed to bit fields are not. Thus, it bears noting.

The following sections of the C99 standard are referenced in the remainder of this answer. The first deals with promotions to different types, the next the valuation and potential value-change (if any). The last is important in understanding how a bit-fields `int`-type is determined.

> **C99-§6.3.1.1: Boolean, characters, and integers**
>
> 2: If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the integer promotions. All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.
>
> **C99-§6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers**
>
> 1. When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
> 2. Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.
> 3. Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.
>
> **C99-§6.7.2.1 Structure and Union Specifiers**
>
> 10: A *bit-field* is interpreted as having a signed or unsigned integer type consisting of the specified number of bits. If the value 0 or 1 is stored into a nonzero-width bit-field of type _Bool, the value of the bit-field shall compare equal to the value stored; a _Bool bit-field has the semantics of a _Bool.

Consider the regular `int` bit representation of your test values. The following are on a 32-bit `int` implementation:

```
value : s  bits 
    2 : 0  0000000 00000000 00000000 00000010   <== note bottom three bits
   -6 : 1  1111111 11111111 11111111 11111010   <== note bottom three bits
    5 : 0  0000000 00000000 00000000 00000101   <== note bottom two bits
```

Walking through each of these, applying the requirements from the standard references above.

**`int parent:3`** :The first field is a 3-bit signed `int`, and is being assigned the decimal value `2`. Does the rvalue type, `int`, encompass the lvalue type, `int:3`? Yes, so the types are good. Does the *value* `2` fit within the range of the lvalue type? Well, `2` can easily fit in an `int:3`, so no value mucking is required either. The first field works fine.

**`int child:3`**: The second field is also a 3-bit signed `int`, this time being assigned the decimal value `-6`. Once again, does the rvalue type (`int`) fully-encompass the lvalue type (`int:3`)? Yes, so again the types are fine. However, the *minimum* bit-count require to represent `-6`, a signed value, is **4** bits. (`1010`), accounting for the most signnificant bit as the sign-bit. Therefore the value `-6` is out of range of the allowable storage of a 3-bit signed bit-field. Therefore, the result is *implementation-defined* per §6.3.1.3-3.

**`int mother:2`** The final field is a 2-bit signed `int`, this time being assigned the decimal value 5. Once again, does the rvalue type (`int`) fully-encompass the lvalue type (`int:2`)? Yes, so again the types are fine. However, once again we're faced with a value that cannot fit within the target-type. The minimum bit-count need for representing a *signed* positive `5` is four: (0101). We only have two to work with. Therefore, the result is once again *implementation-defined* per §6.3.1.3-3.

Therefore, if I take this correctly, the implementation in this case simply hacks off all but the required bits needed to store fill the declared bit depth. And the results of that hackery is what you now have. **2 2 1**

**Note**

It is entirely possible I flipped the order of the promotion incorrectly (it is easy for me to get lost in the standard, as I am dyslexic and flip things in my head periodically). If that is the case I would ask anyone with a stronger interpretation of the standard please point this out to me an I will address the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

The bit fields size for `child` and `mother` are too small to contain the constant values you are assigning to them and they're overflowing.

Answer (score 3):

You can remark that in compilation phase you will get the following warnings:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:18:11: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion
test.c:18:11: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion
```

That because you have defined your variables as 3 bits from an int and not the whole int. Over flow means that is unable to store your values into a 3 bits memory.

so if you use the following structure definition you will avoid the warning in the compilation and you will get the right values:

```
struct m

{
   int parent;

   int child;

   int mother;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't represent -6 in only 3 bits; similarly, you can't represent 5 in only two bits.

Is there a reason why `parent`, `child`, and `mother` need to be bit fields?

Answer (score 2):

`child` requires minimum 4 bits to hold `-6` (`1010`). And `mother` requires minimum 4 bits to hold `5` (`0101`).

`printf` considers only last 3 bits of `child` so its printing `2` and it considers only last 2 bits of `mother` so its printing `1`.

You may think like `child` requires only 3 bits for storing `-6`, but it actually requires 4 bits including sign bit. Negative values use to be stored in 2`s complement mode.

```
Binary equivalent of 6 is 110
one`s complement of 6 is 001
two`s complement of 6 is 010
sign bit should be added at MSB.
```

So value of `-6` is `1010`. `printf` is omiting the sign bit.

Answer (score 1):

The first of all:

`5` is a `101` in binary, so it doesn't fit in 2 bits.

`-6`  also doesn't fit in 3 bits.

Comment: Correction: 5 is a 101 in binary, so it doesn't fit in 2 `bits`

Comment: int mother:2 means to say I'm telling the compiler to allocate only two bits for storing 5.So compiler will start storing from left most side and will store only 10 so the output is 1.

Answer (score 1):

Your bit fields are too small. Also: is this just an exercise, or are you trying to (prematurely) optimize? You're not going to be very happy with the result... it'll be quite slow.

Comment: This type of specifying bits to each structure member is done for optimal storage,for easy access of data.

Comment: And therefor usually unneccessary unless you know that you absolutely need to do this. And slower than a normally padded struct.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the reason after applying thought :-)

2 is represented in binary as 0010

-6 as 1010

and five as 0101

Now 2 can be represented by using only 3 bits so it gets stored as 010

-6 would get stored in 3 bits as 010

and five would get stored in 2 bits as 01

So the final output would be 2 2 1

Thanks everyone for your reply !!!!