# Explain Use of ":" operator in c++ in the code snippet "int i:2;"

Tags: c++, operators, puzzle, bit-fields, twos-complement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does this C++ code mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604968/what-does-this-c-code-mean)

In the following C++ code

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  struct clap
  {
   int i:2;
   int j:2;
   int k:3;
   }x={1,2,3};

  printf("%d %d %d",x.i,x.j,x.k);

  return 0;
}
```

On running the following code, I get the output
1 -2 3

Please Explain the meaning of the ":" operator in reference to the above code, and the reason for this strange output;

Comment: Possible duplicate: [/questions/14336994/c-structure-padding/14337041#14337062](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336994/c-structure-padding/14337041#14337062)

Answer (score 8):

These indicate **bit-fields** with the length being denoted after the colon

```
  struct clap
  {
   int i:2; // length 2
   int j:2; // length 2
   int k:3; // length 3
   };
```

Bitfields save on space. Try computing `sizeof(clap)` and you'll find it is 4 bytes on gcc 4.7. The reason it is not 1 byte (2 + 2 + 3 = 7 bits < 1 byte), is that compilers also align structs on certain boundaries depending on the underyling type of the bitfields. E.g. changing `int` to `short` or `char` as the underlying type of the bitfields will reduce the total size of `clap` to respectively 2 and 1 byte(s) (on gcc 4.7 again).

This should be compared to storing 3 full integers typically takes 12 bytes (if an int is 4 bytes). OTOH, bit-fields can make your code slower because addressing the members entails shifting and unpacking the bitfields.

The sign problem arises because the 2-bits [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) of 2 is equal to -2. Extending the code to `int j:3` will output `2`.

Comment: On running your code , the size of clap comes 4.  Please explain how it is coming?

Comment: You can change the underlying type, using short instead of int, and look at the difference.

Comment: @amol_beast the size of clap is at least the size of the underlying bit-field type. E.g. having only `int i:1` as struct member, already gives `clap` size equal to 4 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

The colon in the structure means that the members are *bit fields*. That is, each field only uses the specified number of bits.

That you get `-2` for the field `j` is probably because `printf` treats is as a sign-extended integer.

Comment: Assuming your reason is true , then it should give -3 output for the value of k. Am I correct?

Comment: j has 2 bits, 10, the highest is 1, this is negative. k has 3 bits, 011, the highest is 0, this is non-negative.

Answer (score 2):

That is what's called [bit field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field).

Update:

The reason that `x.j` was printed as `-2`: `x.j` is 2, but it only has 2 bits and the higher bit is 1, which will be taken as the sign bit by `printf` with `%d` format. To verify that, just change `%d` to `%u` and see what happens.

Comment: what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: Not my down vote but I guess you need to describe more instead of short answers

Comment: but I gave a link to wikipedia.

Comment: A link is good but the answer still doesn't contain much info in itself : still too short. You need to explain what is it, how to use it, use cases, side affects etc. then it becomes a good answer.

Comment: +1 from me anyway. Enjoy your time on so.

Comment: And, [links rot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).

Comment: @billz: ok. I believe sometimes is better to give a short hint to "the student" and he self read the documentation. But I guess HERE you are right...  Good advice.

Comment: If it's so short HINT - use comment

Comment: ;-) thus is why I don’t put links, but the worlds to Google. Anyway, I don’t do anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Like other answers say it is bit field. 
One important note about them:

> Thus C++0x treats all (non-zero-length) bit-fields in a contiguous
>   sequence of bit-fields as part of a single memory location; an
>   assignment to one conflicts with an assignment to any of the others.
>   Such contiguous bit-fields should not be updated concurrently by
>   different threads. Usually that means they should be protected by a
>   single lock.

http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/c++mm/threadsintro.html#bitfields