# Why the following code in C prints -1?

Tags: c, structure, bit-fields

I was expecting 1 as the output..

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
struct A{
    int a:1;
};
struct A bb;
bb.a=1;
printf("%d",bb.a);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336994/c-bit-field-variables-are-printing-unexpected-values

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By doing `int a:1`, you are setting `a` as a `1 bit signed int`. It's represented by 1 bit and assuming two's complement representation in your implementation, it has a range of `{0,-1}`. So setting `1` to `a` will represent a value of `-1`.

**Addendum**:

Take notice that by `C90` standard, a plain `int` is a `signed int`; but when it comes to bit-fields, the following holds true:

> A bit-field may have type int , unsigned int , or signed int . Whether the high-order bit position of a plain `int` bit-field is treated as a sign bit is implementation-defined

Comment: Isn't it implementation-defined whether the field is signed or unsigned?

Comment: @Anonymous, yes it is. That's why it's better to be explicit - use `signed int` or `unsigned int` to make the code platform indepdenent.

Comment: Thanks to all for the reply ...                                              @ArjunSreedharan Sreedharan .. why it gives -1 on odd values and 0 on even values..

Comment: @RajeshSethi Since the member is 1-bit, consider only 1 bit of your value- if it's zero, you'll get `0`, if it's one you'll get `-1`. Read more about two's complement.

Comment: @ArjunSreedharan Sreedharan ..an Odd number will have 1 at the least significant bit and and Even number will have 0 at the least significant bit.. so in case of 1 it gives -1 as you explained above and for 0 it gives 0... plz correct if i got it wrong!!

Answer (score 2):

A 1-bit signed field on a two's complement machine can only take the values 0 or -1, Found it here
http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/bitfields.html

Answer (score 1):

Your bit-field is a signed integer of size 1. The only valid signed values of one bit are 0 (`0`) and -1 (`1`), since the most significant (and only) bit is taken to be the sign bit.

You can see it more clearly if you consider two-bit values: 0 (`00`), 1 (`01`), -1 (`11`), -2 (`10`).

If you change to `unsigned int a:1`, you will meet your expectation.